# How to Create a Grouped, Stacked, Bar Chart with Proportionately Split Bar Sections in matplotlib and python? For Loan Portfolio Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, charts

I'm tasked with creating this very complicated bar chart with the purpose of analyzing the joint exposure of loan portfolios to the loans that they share. My data is formatted like the table pictured, where "Loan" signifies a loan, "Level" signifies the trust deed priority, "FMV" signifies the fair market value of the underlying real estate, "Fund" identifies the portfolio that the portion of the loan belongs to, and "Amount" is the amount of that portion of the loan. I need to graph it so that for each unique "Loan", there is:

1. One bar showing the FMV; and
2. One complex bar, where:

   a. the bar is stacked from "1st" level on the bottom up to "3rd" level on top

   b. when multiple "Fund"s hold 2 or more pieces of the same level of the same loan (like in the "2nd" level of sample loan 124 below), the bar section must be split between them, and the width of each section should be in the proportion of their respective amounts, and

   c. they should be colored according to "Fund".

[image: chart problem]

My code is below, but it barely covers point 1 above. I know I'm slowly getting there but I'm truly stumped.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def loan_analysis(data, ax):
    # standardize to $ millions
    chart_loans = (data.reset_index().set_index(
        ["Loan", "Level", "Fund"]) / 1000000).reset_index()

    # create fmv data
    fmv_data = chart_loans.drop_duplicates(
        subset=["Loan"]).set_index("Loan")["FMV"]

    # create seniority/"Level" data
    seniority_data = pd.pivot_table(chart_loans, values="Amount", index=[
                                    "Loan"], columns=["Level"], aggfunc=np.sum)
    seniority_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    # Plot FMVs
    fmv_data.plot.bar(ax=ax, stacked=False, linewidth=0,
                      position=.8, color="darkgreen", legend=True, width=.2)

    # Plot loan exposures
    seniority_data.plot.bar(ax=ax, stacked=True,
                            linewidth=0, position=.1, legend=True)

    # formatting
    def dollar_fmt(x, y):
        return '${:.2f}'.format(x)

    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(dollar_fmt))
    ax.grid(axis='y', which='major', color="lightblue", lw=.1)
    ax.grid(axis='y', which='minor', color="lightblue", lw=.05)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=0)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', length=0)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.set(xlabel='LOAN')

    for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
        tick.set_rotation(0)

    return ax


sample_data = pd.DataFrame({"Loan": ["123", "123", "124", "124", "124", "124"], "Level": ["1st", "1st", "1st", "2nd", "2nd", "3rd"], "FMV": [
                           1000000, 1000000, 3000000, 3000000, 3000000, 3000000], "Fund": ["A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "D"], "Amount": [250000, 250000, 1000000, 700000, 300000, 200000]})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8.5))
ax = plt.axes()

loan_analysis(sample_data, ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is an insane requirement... Some matplotlib nerd may propose an answer (since with matplotlib you may control completly the plot), but I find the chart concept way too complex. Maybe this could help : https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.broken_barh.html. Another approach would be to create a categorical column that computes the sum of 2nd level data, plot this on a main chart, and provide a second chart with the 2nd level details ... Anyway, good luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps someone has a more elegant solution. The following one is not pretty, but does the job.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mtp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def loan_analysis(data, ax):
    # standardize to $ millions
    chart_loans = (data.reset_index().set_index(["Loan", "Level", "Fund"]) / 1000000).reset_index()

    # define xticks
    xticklabels = data.Loan.drop_duplicates().values
    xticks = range(1, 3*len(xticklabels), 3)

    # draw each bar, grouped by loan and level
    indexLoan = 0
    for _, groupLoan in chart_loans.groupby(['Loan']):

        # plot FMV
        plt.bar(x=xticks[indexLoan]-1.1, height=groupLoan.FMV, width=1, bottom=0, color=colors['FMV'], align='edge')
        
        # draw each detailed bar-set
        lastBottom = 0
        for _, groupLevel in groupLoan.groupby(['Level']):

            # amount sum for the given loan and level
            levelSum = np.sum(groupLevel.Amount)

            # draw bars for the given loan and level
            lastPosition = 0
            for i in range(len(groupLevel)):
                tmpGroupIndex = groupLevel.index[i]
                tmpWidth = groupLevel.Amount[tmpGroupIndex] / levelSum
                c = colors[groupLevel.Fund[tmpGroupIndex]]
                p = xticks[indexLoan] + lastPosition

                plt.bar(x=p, height=levelSum, width=tmpWidth, bottom=lastBottom, color=c, align='edge')

                # keep last x-position
                lastPosition += tmpWidth

            # keep last y-position
            lastBottom += levelSum

        indexLoan += 1

    # formatting
    def dollar_fmt(x, y):
        return '${:.2f}'.format(x)

    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtp.ticker.FuncFormatter(dollar_fmt))
    ax.grid(axis='y', which='major', color="lightblue", lw=.1)
    ax.grid(axis='y', which='minor', color="lightblue", lw=.05)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=0)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', length=0)
    ax.set_xticks(xticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.set(xlabel='LOAN')

    # define legend
    plt.legend(handles=[mtp.patches.Patch(color=color, label=label) for label, color in colors.items()])

    return ax

# define fund colors
colors = {
        'A': 'tab:orange', 
        'B': 'tab:green', 
        'C': 'tab:purple', 
        'D': 'tab:olive',
        'FMV': 'k'}

sample_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Loan": ["123", "123", "124", "124", "124", "124"], 
    "Level": ["1st", "1st", "1st", "2nd", "2nd", "3rd"], 
    "FMV": [1000000, 1000000, 3000000, 3000000, 3000000, 3000000], 
    "Fund": ["A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "D"], 
    "Amount": [250000, 250000, 1000000, 700000, 300000, 200000]})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8.5))
ax = plt.axes()

loan_analysis(sample_data, ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is it! I apologize I didn't accept your answer sooner, I didn't have my StackOverflow notifications set up. Unfortunately for me, that also means I didn't see your answer in time for the project deadline, and ended up writing my own solution. Our solutions are incredibly similar, starting with plotting the FMV bars and then programmatically plotting the split loan bars based on their size ratios. I think that serves as validation that it is the best and perhaps only solution. Thank you again for the answer!